# Netcat -z does not return if host not found

Tags: networking, netcat

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. I'm trying to detect that a cable is connected to a camera serving an rtsp stream. My script is invoking

```
nc -zv 10.0.0.3 554
```

and testing the return value (or stderr)

If the cable is connected it works as expected, returning zero, but if the cable is not connected, the command waits forever.

I've tried adding -w 0, and it doesn't help, nor does -n, but -z is supposed to return immediately anyway.

if the host is known, it returns quickly as expected

```
$ nc -zv localhost 554
nc: connect to localhost port 554 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: No not typical behavior, i think. There could be latency on the network, if it is a domain name - lag could be due to nameserver. But you are using an ip so likely network latency. Localhost returns immediately since there is technically no network in a real sense

Comment: May also be due to router or switch ( if you have one connected )

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Which latency would there be with no cable connected? It should produce a no route...

Comment: @vidarlo good point. I was thinking it would be from the router side. But then again, you have a point

Comment: There's no router on that interface, so when the cable is unplugged, the interface disappears from ifconfig.